# Can't show database values in html table PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans

I've been really trying to see what's the problem with the code but I can't so far, thing is i have a database and when i try to show database info on html table it's blank, as if query never got anything.

This is my view model.

```
<body>
    <form action="<?php echo base_url().'HomeController/index'; ?>" method="post">
        <h1>Productos consolas de videojuegos</h1>
        <table>
            <thead style="background-color: orange">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Producto</th>
                    <th>Proveedor</th>
                    <th>Descripción</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php if(!empty($info)){foreach($info as $inf){?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="user id" value="<?php echo $inf->id;?>" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="nombre_producto" value="<?php echo $inf->nombre_producto;?>" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="proveedor" value="<?php echo $inf->nombre_proveedor;?>" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="descripción" value="<?php echo $inf->descripción;?>" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="precio" value="<?php echo $inf->precio;?>" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php }}?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Nombre de tu producto" />

            <button type="submit" name="submit">Buscar</button>>
            <p>Descripcion de la aplicacion: Hacer consultas en la tabla que incluye la base de datos de productos electronicos.<br></p>
            <!-- <p>This is a second paragraph.</p>
             -->
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

And this is my table model

```
class HomeModel extends CI_Model{


    public function getData(){

        $query=$this->db->get('db_simbo');

            return $query->result();



    }   

   public function search_product($nombre_producto){

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('db_simbo');
        $this->db->like('nombre_producto',$nombre_producto);

        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            return $query->result();

        }

        else{

            return $query->result();

        }
    }
```

and this is controller

```
 class HomeController extends CI_Controller{
  public function index(){
      $data = NULL;
      $this->load->model('HomeModel',$data);

      $config = array();
     if($this->input->post() != ''){
          $nombre_producto = $this->input->post('search');

          if (isset($nombre_producto) and !empty($nombre_producto)) {
            $data ['info'] = $this->HomeModel->search_product($nombre_producto);
           }
      }
      else{
          $data ['info'] = $this->HomeModel->getData();
      }


     $this->load->view('HomeView',$data);
     }
```

Comment: first in view `var_dump($info)` check you get expected result .

Comment: var_dump only shows after i hit submit button, then it shows the value i looked for, is there a way i can show table with values from the start, before clicking submit button?.

Comment: **write a log file in the controller** that gets data from the model and writes into a log file.